# How to obtain the current executing directory irrespective of the host type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code snippet that loads some assemblies from the current executing directory at runtime. 
The code is part of a library that can be hosted in a console app/windows service/aspnet web app etc.

Is there a single API call that will provide the current directory the code is running from?
For a console/windows service `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` returns the correct 
path but the same call in an ASPNET app returns the path to the virtual root instead of the path 
to the **[virtualroot]\bin** directory of the web app.

For ASPNET `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath;` returns what I want.

I could make a check like the following so that I get the correct path irrespective of the host:

```
 string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath ??
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

This sort of heuristic seems a bit hackish and I was hoping there is a single API call that will provide the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check where the current assebly is stored you can use this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

Or if your code is in a library and you wand the location of the started exe you can use `GetEntryAssembly()`.

The codeBase is in URI syntax. To get the path (if required) you can use:

```
var path = new Uri(codeBase).AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: This lead me in the right direction! This works:                        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot that you need only the directory.